# Expanding __consumer_offsets topics to multiple new nodes in cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

Initially we had a 5 node Kafka cluster which was expanded to 7 nodes. Post expansion, the heavier topics were added with more partitions and reassignment was done to spread them to the additional nodes and the setup is working as expected. Is it safe to add more partitions to the __consumer_offsets topic as well and run the partition assignment script to evenly distribute the partitions across the cluster. Since this is a Kafka internal topic, I am quite cautious before making any changes.

The Kafka version used is 2.4

Comment: did you try this then ?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem in reassignment of __consumer_offsets topic. It is just like any other topic in Kafka